# eclipse CDT: how to use scroll bar in mac OS

Tags: eclipse, macos, scroll, scrollbar

Now I use eclipse CDT but one thing really annoys me.
See this picture:
[image]

I cannot use the scroll bar. It only shows up when I move my fingers up and down on my trackpad, and disappears quickly. But scrolling up and down in this way is really inconvenient!!

**Edit**
Okay. I do not fully solve this problem, but now I find a way to relieve my pain. Window ->Editor ->Toggle split editor. Then, the editor panel is splitted into upper and lower parts, showing different parts of the same file. And in this case, I can drag the scroll bar up and down!

Comment: Do other applications behave this way? If so, I think you need to change your settings because there is definitely one that changes when the scrollbar is visible.

Comment: @Laurel Other applications, such as safari and adobe reader, are good. For now, it's only eclipse CDT on my mac.

Comment: You could look to see if Eclipse has its own setting.

Comment: @Laurel Yes. That's what I'm doing. Look into its preferences. But for now I do not know how to set something related to the bar.